# Cygwin with some kind of keyring

Tags: cygwin, ssh-keys

It would be nice to only have to type my SSH key passphrase once, as it works on Mac OSX. Per session at least. This would ease my programming related (!) tasks :)

Could this be done somehow?

Answer (score 1):

See [Keychain](http://www.gentoo.org/doc/en/keychain-guide.xml), a bash script developed by Gentoo.  See also [drobbin's intro to Keychain](http://www.funtoo.org/en/security/keychain/intro/), with a download link.

Comment: Executing `exec ssh-agent /usr/bin/bash` and then `ssh-add` works perfectly. But when I try to load it automatically by adding those lines to .bashrc och .bash_profile, I am never asked for my password. The same happends when I try the instructions for `Keychain`. Does it work for you?

Comment: If `ssh-agent` has your passphrase, it won't ask for it.  Try killing `ssh-agent` and then starting a terminal.